# How to remove null value from array using aggregation in monodb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Query:**

```
{ "$match":{ "followuser": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.user_id),"status":1 }},
        { '$lookup':{ from: 'users',localField: 'user',foreignField: '_id', as: 'followerDetails' } },
         { '$unwind': '$followerDetails'},
         { '$match': { "followerDetails.status" :1}},
         { '$lookup':{ from: 'shops',localField: 'user',foreignField: 'shop_owner',
         as: 'shopDetails' } },
         { '$unwind': '$shopDetails'},
         { '$lookup':{ from: 'follow_user',localField: 'followerDetails._id',foreignField: 'followuser',as: 'checkfollowstatus' } },
          { $unwind: { path: "$checkfollowstatus", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
            { '$lookup':{ from: 'product',localField: 'shopDetails._id',foreignField: 'shop',as: 'productDetails' } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$productDetails", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
            {
                "$group": {
                    _id: '$_id',
                    followerDetails:{$first:"$followerDetails"},shopDetails:{ $first:"$shopDetails"},
                    checkfollowstatus:{$first:"$checkfollowstatus"},
                    productDetails: {
                        "$addToSet": {
                            $cond: [{$eq: ["$productDetails.status", 1]}, "$productDetails",null ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

actually in aggregation query  in $cond else case i'm replacing with 'null' then i'm pushing to the array the array i coming like **"productDetails": [null],**. how can i make like this **"productDetails": [],**  using aggregation query
**result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "count": 2,
    "documentData": [
      {
       "_id": "56f39a0c0a6eb27f8cc40189",
       "followerDetails": {},
       "shopDetails": {},
       "checkfollowstatus": [],
       "productDetails": [
                          null
        ],
       "numberOfProduct": 1
      },
    {
     "_id": "56f399730a6eb27f8cc40188",
         "followerDetails": {},
          "shopDetails": {},
          "checkfollowstatus": [],
        "productDetails": [
           null
       ],
       "numberOfProduct": 1
      }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Probably more of the concen here is that **all** the values are `null`, which would seem ot indicate you are doing something really wrong. As for "removal" just use `$filter` or actually considering these are sourced by `$addToSet` you can just apply `$setDifferece` to compare the array element to another array as `[null]`. Which of course removes the element since the resulting "set" is the "difference" between the two.

Comment: *$lookup...$unwind...$lookup...$unwind...$lookup...$unwind...* this really looks as if you are using MongoDB as if it were a relational database, not a document database.